# Error in testing componentWillMount to componentDidMount, Migration to React 17

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm trying to migrate to React 17 but most of the test fails because of the update to `componentWillMount` to `componentDidMount`. So the problem is when the components mount it didn't receive any props, so it prints an error.

Before

```js
componentWillMount () {
    this.isNewComment = this.checkIsNewComment(this.props.comments)
}
```

After

```js
componentDidMount () {
    this.isNewComment = this.checkIsNewComment(this.props.comments)
}
```

Test

```js
test('Should return false if the connected car has existing comments', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<VehicleNotesCard {...mockProps} />)
    const comments = { commentText: 'Comment of the connected car' }

    expect(wrapper.instance().checkIsNewComment(comments)).toBeFalsy()
})
```

function checkIsNewComment

```js
checkIsNewComment (comments) {
    return comments === undefined || comments === null || !comments.commentText
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: `componentWillMount` is going to be removed in React 17. With that said its not released yet how are you migrating to it?

Comment: @Rikin well to 16.9, but my company tell me to do it, any suggestion for the test?

Comment: Reading your test setup, first you are mounting so mount and render already happened and then you are calling mounted instance's `checkIsNewComment` function which does something and you are expecting whatever it returns to be falsy. Can you post what `checkIsNewComment` look like

Comment: @Rikin is updated, hope to be more clear

Comment: Can you try to `console.log(wrapper.instance())` in your test and see if the underlying function `checkIsNewComment` is exposed in it. Also was your test working before the upgrade?

Comment: @Rikin doesn't print the console log :(

Comment: You can put it directly in the constructor

Comment: @Foyarash neither that way is working :(